# How to verify 64 bit compatibility?

Tags: c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I'd like to ensure that my 32bit ported code works correctly when the memory allocation address goes into the >4GB memory range.

Is it a good idea to allocate 4GB in my main method at the beginning ?

Is it better to set the base address outside the 32bit range ?
Is it necessary to set the base address in every dynamically linked library ?

Not necessary to mention that i already looked at static code analyzer results and reviewed my code.

Comment: Why do you think it might not work? Are you doing something funny with your pointers? Manipulating the address bits directly somehow?

Comment: *Portable* code" is far-superior to "ported" code (though the former is always a challenge on Windoze). Addressing memory beyond 4GB is only one small part of whether your code will be 64-bit compliant. There are *plenty* of other issues that would/could be encountered. Ex: assuming the octet size of anything larger than a `char` type. And, no guarantee the CRT may *already* serving up addresses that use the high 32 bits of a ptr. So that comfort is faux to begin with. And `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO` is no silver bullet either. In short, no simple solution without some work.

Comment: I looked into these [examples of porting issues](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/) and i'd like to ensure that issue number 6 doesn't happen in our application. The two ideas to test this problem are mentioned in my post. Setting /BASE or [/FIXED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w368ysh2.aspx) in the linker section or allocate enough memory on application startup. But i'm not sure which way is the better one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to go some way to stress testing this aspect of your program is to use top down memory allocation. That can be enabled system wide via a registry setting as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190527.aspx

That your program may run correctly with this setting won't prove that it is correct though. Top down memory allocation is just one way to flush out some of the most typical 32/64 bit bugs.

Comment: Good idea, thank you! What do you think of the /BASE or /FIXED idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can force a load address above 4GB. Worth a try though.